# Commercial 3DoF/6DoF trajectory simulation and optimization tool for launch vehicle

Tags: orbital-mechanics, launch-vehicle, flight-computer, launch-trajectories, trajectory-design

Is there any 3DoF/6DoF trajectory simulation and optimization tool for launch vehicles like POST available commercially? If there whether it's how reliable when it comes to using for real-time projects

Comment: please provide a reference for POST vehicles.

Comment: It looks like [STK Missile Toolkit](https://p.widencdn.net/ncfk8n/MMT-Product-Specsheet) + [STK](http://help.agi.com/stk/index.htm#stk/ObjectMap_Vehicle_Rocket.htm%3FTocPath%3DGetting%2520Started%7CBuild%2520a%2520Scenario%7CAdd%2520STK%2520Objects%7CObject%2520Properties%7C_____14) provides a lot of functionality for launch trajectories.

Comment: @J.Doe  POST is the Program for Optimization of Simulated Trajectories, an ITAR restricted code used by NASA and DoD. The questioner is asking for a similar code, not similar vehicles.

Comment: Ya, I know that ITAR restriction for the POST program. That's why I would like to know any private companies providing a similar type of program for trajectory design and optimization.